# Converting 'String' Type in Swift to 'const char *' in C++

Tags: c++, swift, interop

I have the below code where my Swift code calls a C++ function. In this the Swift calls a C++ function and passes a Swift `String` as an argument to it, which is then received in the C++ code as `const char *`. This conversion works without any errors. Is this a documented behaviour in C++-Swift interoperability and is this safe to use?

Swift side:

```swift
internal static func CharCheck (pSentence: String) -> Void {
    TWSoundLogic.CharacterSoundCount (pSentence)
}
```

In the C++ side,

```cpp
void TWSoundLogic::CharacterSoundCount (const char * pSentence) {
    ..
}
```

However, on returning a `String` type from a Swift function and trying to receive it as a `const char*` in C++, it gives an error in C++. Below is the code.

> No viable conversion from 'swift::String' to 'const char *'

Swift side:

```swift
internal static func CharCheck () -> String {
    ..
    return sentence
}
```

In the C++ side,

```cpp
void TWSoundLogic::CharacterSoundCount (const char * pSentence) {
    const char * cppsentence = swiftClass::CharCheck(); //error
}
```

Why does it not allow to return, but it allows to pass as argument? Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: You posted the code that works, but you should always post the code that doesn't work as well. It's hard to describe code, it's much better to post code.

Comment: You could try https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/#using-stdstring

Comment: @VipulGupta Well I don't know swift, but this looks like the difference between constructing a `std::string` from a `char*` (which C++ allows automatically) and extracting a `char*` from a `std::string` (which C++ allows but does not happen automatically). In C++ code generally you should prefer `std::string` to `char*`.

Comment: I think it should be `TWSoundLogic::CharCech()`.

Comment: Maybe you better transfer swift's String to C string(which is char*).
You can do so with this function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstring

Comment: `internal static func CharCheck (pSentence: String) -> Void 
 {
    TWSoundLogic.CharacterSoundCount (pSentence.cString(using: .utf8))
 }`

Comment: Reading the doc that @AlanBirtles linked, it looks like the line of least resistance is to create a wrapper function (in Swift) that converts the Swift `String` to a C++ `std.string` (`std::string`) and returns that. It would look like `func charCheckCxx() -> std.string { return std.string(CharCheck()) }`

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses a variety of different internal storage methods to store String objects. I would suggest the following:

Convert your String to `Data` using a specific encoding like UTF8.

Pass the resulting `Data` (Which is a memory buffer) to C++ as a Char *. You'll need to work out ownership of the resulting memory. I haven't dealt with interoperability between Swift and C++ so I'm not sure how to go about that. Off the top of my head I'd say give Swift a way to ask C++ to allocate (malloc) a buffer sized for the contents of the Data, then cast that data to an unsafe mutable buffer and copy the data into it. It would then be your C++ code's responsibility to release the malloc'ed buffer once it is done with it.

Your C++ code will need to be written to assume the encoding (e.g. UTF8)